# Blocking operations in URLConnection

Tags: java, networking, blocking

Running the following code snippet:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
URLConnection urlconn = url.openConnection();
urlconn.connect();
urlconn.getContentLength();
```

I get the dead-lock sometimes, usually at two lines: `urlconn.connect()` and `urlconn.getContentLength()`. Also, when I do

```
InputStream is = urlconn.getInputStream();
// doing some reading
is.close();
```

I also get blocking at `is.close()`. I want to ask why such blocking happens. It is clueless to me from the Java API.

Comment: a similar issue talked before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999340/httpurlconnection-getting-locked

Comment: I think a better question to ask is, why do you think it shouldn't be? Given the fact that connect needs to establish a socket connects to another computer and negotiate the protocol, and get content basically is doing a socket.getInputStream.read

Comment: You don't get a deadlock. You get a block. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @EJB How to solve this situation if read() and close() both block? Create a new connection and kill the old connection thread? (We have a case where the read() block forever, probably due some bug in the sender, or in a lib)